# julia-lang save/load sparse matrix to/from file efficiently

Tags: julia

`writedlm` save a large matrix size, e.g. (100000,1000), with a few none zeros in a very big file ~1Gb. Is there any more efficient method?

Comment: `SparseArray` and the package `JLD`

Comment: Thank you. I used SparseArray but saw no method to save it best. JLD does it appropriately.

Comment: No probs. Feel free to post the code you derived from my comment as an answer to your own question. I didn't do this myself as I've actually never used those packages (I just knew they were the "right" way to do what you were after).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Colin mentioned, `SparseArray` and the package `JLD` will do:

```
using JLD
a = speye(1_000_000)
save("/tmp/foo.jld","a",a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Seralization` package `serialize()`/`deserialize()` if you don't care about the opacity of the format.

```
 # write to file
 using Serialization
 using SparseArrays

 a = speye(1000000)
 f = open("mat.dat","w")
 serialize(f, a)
 close(f)

 # read back
 a = deserialize(open("mat.dat"))
 # may need to close the file
```

Comment: It'd be better to use do blocks here instead of plain `open` and `close` function calls.